# Drawing an OpenGL triangle in Python

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

Here is my code so far:

main.py_

```
    from Application import Application

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = Application()
        app.run()
```

Triangle.py_

```
    import contextlib
    import logging as log
    from OpenGL import GL as gl
    import ctypes
    import sys

    class Triangle:
        vertex_array_id = 0
        vertex_data = []
        program_id = 0
        shader_id = 0

        def __init__(self):
            print('Triangle.__init__(self)')
            self.create_vertex_buffer()
            self.load_shaders()


        def create_vertex_array_object(self):
            log.debug('create_vertex_array_object(self):')
            self.vertex_array_id = gl.glGenVertexArrays(1)
            try:
                gl.glBindVertexArray(self.vertex_array_id)
                yield
            finally:
                log.debug('~create_vertex_array_object(self):')
                gl.glDeleteVertexArrays(1, [self.vertex_array_id])



        def create_vertex_buffer(self):
            with self.create_vertex_array_object():
                # A triangle
                self.vertex_data = [-1, -1, 0,
                               1, -1, 0,
                               0, 1, 0]
                attr_id = 0  # No particular reason for 0,
                # but must match the layout location in the shader.

                log.debug('creating and binding the vertex buffer (VBO)')
                vertex_buffer = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
                try:
                    gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer)

                    array_type = (gl.GLfloat * len(self.vertex_data))
                    gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                                    len(self.vertex_data) * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float),
                                    array_type(*self.vertex_data),
                                    gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

                    log.debug('setting the vertex attributes')
                    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(
                        attr_id,  # attribute 0.
                        3,  # components per vertex attribute
                        gl.GL_FLOAT,  # type
                        False,  # to be normalized?
                        0,  # stride
                        None  # array buffer offset
                    )
                    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_id)  # use currently bound VAO
                    yield
                finally:
                    log.debug('cleaning up buffer')
                    # gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(attr_id)
                    # gl.glDeleteBuffers(1, [vertex_buffer])


        def load_shaders(self):
            shaders = {
                gl.GL_VERTEX_SHADER: '''\
                    #version 330 core
                    layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
                    void main(){
                      gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
                      gl_Position.w = 1.0;
                    }
                    ''',
                gl.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER: '''\
                    #version 330 core
                    out vec3 color;
                    void main(){
                      color = vec3(1,0,0);
                    }
                    '''
            }
            log.debug('creating the shader program')
            self.program_id = gl.glCreateProgram()
            try:
                shader_ids = []
                for shader_type, shader_src in shaders.items():
                    self.shader_id = gl.glCreateShader(shader_type)
                    gl.glShaderSource(self.shader_id, shader_src)

                    log.debug(f'compiling the {shader_type} shader')
                    gl.glCompileShader(self.shader_id)

                    # check if compilation was successful
                    result = gl.glGetShaderiv(self.shader_id, gl.GL_COMPILE_STATUS)
                    info_log_len = gl.glGetShaderiv(self.shader_id, gl.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)
                    if info_log_len:
                        logmsg = gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(self.shader_id)
                        log.error(logmsg)
                        sys.exit(10)

                    gl.glAttachShader(self.program_id, self.shader_id)
                    shader_ids.append(self.shader_id)

                log.debug('linking shader program')
                gl.glLinkProgram(self.program_id)

                # check if linking was successful
                result = gl.glGetProgramiv(self.program_id, gl.GL_LINK_STATUS)
                info_log_len = gl.glGetProgramiv(self.program_id, gl.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)
                if info_log_len:
                    logmsg = gl.glGetProgramInfoLog(self.program_id)
                    log.error(logmsg)
                    sys.exit(11)

                log.debug('installing shader program into rendering state')
                gl.glUseProgram(self.program_id)
                yield
            finally:
                log.debug('cleaning up shader program')
                for self.shader_id in self.shader_ids:
                    gl.glDetachShader(self.program_id, self.shader_id)
                    gl.glDeleteShader(self.shader_id)
                gl.glUseProgram(0)
                gl.glDeleteProgram(self.program_id)

        def render(self):
            gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)  # Starting from vertex 0
```

Application.py_

```
    import contextlib
    import glfw
    import sys
    from OpenGL import GL as gl
    import logging as log

    from Triangle import Triangle

    class Application:

        tri = Triangle()

        def __init__(self):
            print("Application.__init__(self)")

        @contextlib.contextmanager
        def create_main_window(self):
            log.debug('create_main_window(self):')
            if not glfw.init():
                sys.exit(1)
            try:
                glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
                glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
                glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, True)
                glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
                title = 'Tutorial 2: First Triangle'
                window = glfw.create_window(500, 400, title, None, None)
                if not window:
                    sys.exit(2)
                glfw.make_context_current(window)
                gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.4, 0)
                yield window

            finally:
                log.debug('~create_main_window(self):')
                glfw.terminate()

        def main_loop(self, window):
            while (
                    glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_ESCAPE) != glfw.PRESS and
                    not glfw.window_should_close(window)
            ):
                gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
                self.tri.render()
                glfw.swap_buffers(window)
                glfw.poll_events()

        def run(self):
            log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG)
            with self.create_main_window() as window:
                self.main_loop(window)
```

From the console I have this coming out:

> ```
> DEBUG:root:create_main_window(self):
> Triangle.__init__(self)
> Application.__init__(self)
> DEBUG:root:~create_main_window(self):
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\prussos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 5, in <module>
>    app.run()
>    File "C:\Users\prussos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\Application.py", line 51, in run
>    self.main_loop(window)
>    File "C:\Users\prussos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\Application.py", line 44, in main_loop
>    self.tri.render()
>    File "C:\Users\prussos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\Triangle.py", line 131, in render
>    gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)  # Starting from vertex 0
>    File "C:\Users\prussos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
>    return self( *args, **named )
>    File "C:\Users\prussos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py", line 230, in glCheckError
>    raise self._errorClass(
> OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
>    err = 1282,
>    description = b'invalid operation',
>    baseOperation = glDrawArrays,
>    cArguments = (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
> )
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

There seems to be a drawing error that is happening but I really I not quite exactly sure how to start to troubleshoot this thing yet. The code was moved over from gitlabs into a class based system for python. So a draw arrays that is an invalid operation what could that be coming from in OpenGL library is anyone familiar with it enough to know what place to edit here?

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the code formatting. Use a new code listing for each file. Is `create_vertex_buffer()` even being executed before `render()` is called?

Comment: Oh....   The triangles constructor executes but I seem to be missing create_vertex_buffer and create_vertex_array_object as those functions are defined.

Comment: That the functions are not being executed is being pointed out so the surmising would be that OpenGL is missing stuff maybe buffers because of that problem. Being new to the python language I am a little bit lost here how come they don't execute?

Comment: I am using Python 3.11.0 with packages downloaded from PyCharm's virtual environment for Windows.

Comment: The yields need to be removed. So in python yield if that were a wait for the context manager to clean up? So it does display a triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call an OpenGL instruction, you need a valid and up-to-date OpenGL context. The OpenGL Context is created with the OpenGl window. The OpenGL objects (VAO, VBO and shaders) are create in the constructor of the `Triangle` class. Therefore you can construct an object of this class only after creating the OpenGL window:

```py
class Application:

    # tri = Triangle()              # <-- DELETE

    def __init__(self):
        print("Application.__init__(self)")

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def create_main_window(self):
        log.debug('create_main_window(self):')
        if not glfw.init():
            sys.exit(1)
        try:
            glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
            glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
            glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, True)
            glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
            title = 'Tutorial 2: First Triangle'
            window = glfw.create_window(500, 400, title, None, None)
            if not window:
                sys.exit(2)
            glfw.make_context_current(window)
            gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.4, 0)
            yield window

        finally:
            log.debug('~create_main_window(self):')
            glfw.terminate()

    def main_loop(self, window):

        self.tri = Triangle()          # IINSERT

        while (
                glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_ESCAPE) != glfw.PRESS and
                not glfw.window_should_close(window)
        ):
            gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            self.tri.render()
            glfw.swap_buffers(window)
            glfw.poll_events()

    def run(self):
        log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG)
        with self.create_main_window() as window:
            self.main_loop(window)
```